# PHP get like rows in array

Tags: php, arrays

i have array an with this result :

```
Array
(
    [A] => Array
        (
            [0] => A 
            [1] => B 
            [2] => C 
        )

    [B] => Array
        (
            [0] =>AA
            [1] =>BB
            [2] =>CC
        )

    [C] => Array
        (
            [0] =>AAA
            [1] =>BBB
            [2] =>CCC
        )
)
```

i want to get like rows and print like with this result to each row:

```
A    AA    AAA
B    BB    BBB
C    CC    CCC
```

how to use `foreach` to print that result?

```
foreach ($result as $kk => $arr)
{
   foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
    {
        if ( $k == 'A')
               echo $arr[0];
        if ( $k == 'B')
              echo $arr[1];
        if ( $k == 'B')
            echo $arr[2]."<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: `foreach(call_user_func_array('array_map',array_merge(array(NULL),$result)) as $line){` works, but your colleagues might not like the obscurity. Using a [`MultipleIterator`](http://www.php.net/MultipleIterator) is a somewhat nices way to do it.

Comment: @Wrikken thanks. in this foreach i want to have each sub array into array such as: `$arr=array('A','AA','AAA')` can you help me for that?

Comment: That is exactly the question I was answering. Did you take that code snippet I gave you for a test drive?

Comment: @TuxWorld: That's what it already does: https://eval.in/99494

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new tmp variable for storing our new order.

```
$tmp = array();
```

How deep will the array go? In your example we go down 3 levels..

```
$depth = 3;
```

The array you want to sort

```
$result = array(
    'a' => array( 'a', 'b', 'c' ),
    'b' => array( 'aa', 'bb', 'cc' ),
    'c' => array( 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc' ),
);
```

For each level in $result down to $depth.

```
for ($i=0; $i<$depth; $i++)
{
    // Loop true our results and push them in to the right position in our $tmp array.
    foreach ($result as $row)
    {
        $tmp[$i][] = $row[$i];
    }
}
```

Output var_dump($tmp):

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "a"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "aa"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "aaa"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "b"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "bb"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "bbb"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "c"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "cc"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "ccc"
  }
}
```

And of course.. to print out your re-ordered array with foreach:

```
foreach($tmp as $row) {
    echo "{$row[0]} {$row[1]} {$row[2]}";
}
```

will give you:

```
a aa aaa 
b bb bbb 
c cc ccc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you denote your input as $hash, then $result will have the array in the form that you need:

```
$arr = array_values($hash);
$result = array();
$len = count($arr);
$lenNested = count($arr[0]);
for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++){
    for($j = 0; $j < $lenNested; $j++){
     $result[$j][$i] = $arr[$i][$j];
    }
}
```

This is just transposition of $hash. Now you can print out **$result** line by line.